# Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, use-strict

I have been told by IE11 that `var self = this` is a read-only variable... Yet I am not assigning anything to it after its declaration point. The only variable is height that is changing. Even though, i would be able to change it when using `var`

'use strict';

```
    var onDocumentLoad = require('fe-client-utils/src/dom/onDocumentLoad');
    var onOrientationChange = require('fe-client-utils/src/dom/onOrientationChange');

    var faPageHeight = function () {

    };

    var FA = {
        init: function () {
            this.faAddons = document.querySelector('.fa-addons');
            this.faFooter = document.querySelector('.fa-footer');
            this.extraWideChild = document.querySelector('.extraWide > div');
            this.extraWide = document.querySelector('.extraWide');
            this.faPages = document.querySelector('.fa-pages');
            this.pageContent = document.getElementById('page-content');
            this.faPageItems =  document.querySelectorAll('.fa-page');
            this.moveElements();
            this.faPageHeight();
        },
        faPageHeight: function () {
            var height = 0;
            var self = this;

            Object.keys(self.faPageItems).forEach(function (item, index) {
                height += self.faPageItems[item].offsetHeight;
            });

            height += 150;
            this.extraWideChild.style.height = height+'px';
        },
        moveElements: function () {
            this.faAddons.style = '';

            this.pageContent.appendChild(this.faAddons);
            this.pageContent.appendChild(this.faFooter);

            this.faFooter.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    onDocumentLoad(function () {
        FA.init();
    });

    onOrientationChange(function () {
        FA.faPageHeight();
    });
```

[image]

I get the following error `SCRIPT5045: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode`

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230269(v=vs.94).aspx) you should not be able to re-write a  read-only property. I don't believe I am. So why do I get the error?

> - Read-only property
> - Writing to a read-only property
> - SCRIPT5045: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode
> - JavaScript
> - `var testObj = Object.defineProperties({}, {
>         prop1: {
>             value: 10,
>             writable: false // by default
>         },
>         prop2: {
>             get: function () {
>             }
>         }
>     });
>     testObj.prop1 = 20; 
>     testObj.prop2 = 30;`

Comment: Are you sure that's the line causing the error? I can't replicate that

Comment: Interesting. I'll update the question with the full file. I wonder if encapsulating it all in an object is the cause

Comment: a minimal, complete and verifiable example of code that demonstrates the issue would be better

Comment: It could well be that 'self' is a reserved word in IE11 Strict - try changing it to 'myself' or 'currElm' and see what happens.

Answer (score 7):

This was the last thing that I ever expected to fix this issue. I did also as comments have suggested believe it was the `self` var as it is reserved.

However the line that broke it was:

```
this.faAddons.style = '';
```

Nothing to do with the line that `IE` suggested.

So of course, I set this to remove the attribute rather than just setting it to blank.

```
this.faAddons.removeAttribute('style')
```